# Is an open web socket connection blocking ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, websocket

Just a quick question for general understanding. Could it be, that an open web socket connection is blocking ajax requests? Because ajax requests before initalization of the web socket connections work just fine and after I have established the web socket connection nothing is happening.

```
$.ajax({
   url: someUrl
}).done(function(data) {
    // stuff done and calling initWebSocket()
}).error(function(data) {
  // error stuff done
});

function initWebSocket() { 

    hostname = 'somehost';

    ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + hostname + ':' + wsPort);

    ws.onopen = function() {

    console.log('Connected');

    ws.send(initMessage);
}

ws.onmessage = function(msg) {

// do stuff on message received

}

ws.onclose = function() {
console.log('Disconnected');
}

}

$('#someButton').click(function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
url: someUrl
}).done(function(data) {
console.log(data);
}).error(function(data) {
console.log(data);
});

});
```

Well as mentioned the first ajax request works, the second when I am clicking a button not. Has anybody information on this topic and if web sockets are really blocking ajax request what would be a workaround to get it running? Thanks.

Comment: +1 I'm also seeing the same issue in Chrome when using websockets with SignalR. If I change SignalR to use longpolling, it doesn't block other AJAX requests. Would like to get an answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

The call should be asynchronous, but perhaps the connect is failing. Try adding an onerror handler for the websocket and see what happens.

```
ws.onerror = function(){ console.log(evt.data); }
```

Also, if you could make a JSFiddle or include the HTML it might be that the button event handler is wrong and it isn't related to the websocket code at all.